# Can't correct my java program

Tags: java, arrays

I just started learning java and I'm working on a program. I'm getting an error here:

```
locationsOfCells = simpleDotCom.getLocationCells();
```

but I'm not sure what the error is. Eclipse say

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   `getLocationCells()` from the type `simpleDotCom`

Can someone help me with this? What am I doing wrong?

```
public class simpleDotCom {
    int[] locationsCells;

    void setLocationCells(int[] loc){
        //Setting the array
        locationsCells = new int[3];
        locationsCells[0]= 3;
        locationsCells[1]= 4;
        locationsCells[2]= 5;
    }

    public int[] getLocationCells(){

        return locationsCells;

    }
}

public class simpleDotComGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printBoard();
    }

    private static void printBoard(){
        simpleDotCom theBoard = new simpleDotCom();
        int[] locationsOfCells; 
        locationsOfCells = new int[3];
        locationsOfCells = theBoard.getLocationCells();

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.println(locationsOfCells[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Simple solution is either define your method as `static` or create an object of `simpleDotCom` in main and then call  `obj.getLocationCells()'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are calling the `getLocationCells()` method as if it was a static method when in fact it is an instance method.

You need to first create an object from your class like this:

```
simpleDotCom myObject = new simpleDotCom();
```

and then call the method on it:

```
locationsOfCells  = myObject.getLocationCells();
```

Incidentally, there is a widely followed naming convention in the Java world, where class names always start with a capital letter - you should rename your class to `SimpleDotCom` to avoid confusion.

Comment: I've change the code in question with a new one I just edited but I'm still getting an error at `locationsOfCells = theBoard.getLocationCells();` the error is `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field theBoard`

Comment: you need to move the line that creates theBoard inside the printBoard() method, then it should work

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting `getLocationCells` in a static way. You need to create an instance of `simpleDotCom` first:

```
simpleDotCom mySimpleDotCom = new simpleDotCom();       
locationsOfCells = mySimpleDotCom.getLocationCells();
```

BTW class names always start with a capital letter. This would help remove the confusion of accessing the method as a member method.

Update:

To access from your updated static method, you would need to declare `theBoard` as a `static` variable also:

```
static simpleDotCom theBoard = new simpleDotCom();
```

Comment: I've change the code in question with a new one I just edited but I'm still getting an error at `locationsOfCells = theBoard.getLocationCells();` the error is `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field theBoard`

Comment: You are accessing the variable from a static method. To fix, see my update.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to reference a non static method from the main method. That is not permitted in java. You can try making that simpleDotCom Class as static, so that u can have access to the methods of that class.

Answer (score 1):

```
simpleDotCom obj = new simpleDotCom();
locationsOfCells = obj.getLocationCells();
```

And also your class name should start with a capital letter

Comment: I've change the code in question with a new one I just edited but I'm still getting an error at `locationsOfCells = theBoard.getLocationCells();` the error is `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field theBoard`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a normal non static method from a static context, it does not work.

You can either remove the static word from the routine where you try to access the: `getLocationCells()` from, or make `getLocationCells()` static by adding the static word in its declaration.

Comment: oh thanks for the help. the book I'm reading hasn't talk about static yet.

Comment: but when I add a static to getLocationCells() it say gives me an error when I `return locationsCells;` Eclips gives me this error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field locationsCells`

Comment: try to make the locationsCells static too.

Answer (score 0):

Either make simpleDotCom's fields and methods static, too, or create an instance of simpleDotCom and access the instance's method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have some more errors.

1. The non static method couldn't call up with class name. So try to call the getLocationCells() with object.

   simpleDotCom obj=new simpleDotCom();
   obj.getLocationCells()
2. Next u will get the null pointer exception. U try to print the locationsOfCells values before it is initialized. So try call the setLocationCells() method before printing values.
3. Ur method definition void setLocationCells(int[] loc). Here u having the parameter loc but u didn't use any where in the method block. So please aware of handling method parameter.